# How to change the Hyperlink colour in CDMarkdownKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, markdown

I am using CDMarkdownKit library for Markdown link. Now I want to change the hyperlink text color as per my specs. But I am not able to change the hyperlink text color.

Can you please suggest some other good library for markdown.

Please see the below code snippet,

```
   self.codeLabel.delegate = self
   let markdown = "https://www.google.com/, This *framework* helps **with** parsing `markdown`.[Link](https://www.google.com/)"
    // Create parser
   let markdownParser = CDMarkdownParser(font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16)!,
                                          boldFont: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16),
                                          italicFont: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16),
                                          fontColor: UIColor.darkGray,
                                          backgroundColor: UIColor.clear)

   //It's not working 
   markdownParser.link.color = UIColor.red

   markdownParser.automaticLink.color = UIColor.yellow
   codeLabel.attributedText = markdownParser.parse(markdown)
   codeLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a UITextView to render the markdown,set the property `linkTextAttributes` of by yourself. You have to do this because `UITextView` handles links by itself.

The [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618632-linktextattributes) says:

> The default attributes specify blue text with a single underline and the pointing hand cursor.

So your solution will be:

```
self.codeLabel.linkTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```